# Relacionar misma clave foranea 2 veces en modelo de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy desarrollando un modelo de datos para una aplicación en la que se relacionarán usuarios de diferentes roles con entrenamientos programados a esos usuarios.

Mi modelo de datos de momento solo tiene las siguientes entidades:

- roles
- usuarios
- entrenamientos
- detalle_entrenamientos

Teniendo esto, tengo de momento dos tipos de roles, (entrenador y atleta). Mi duda es ¿Cómo puedo relacionar dos usuarios en la entidad entrenamiento? Es decir, en un entrenamiento debe figurar un corredor y un entrenador y los dos son usuarios de la plataforma.

Comment: tal vez con una tabla intermedia, con una relación de muchos a muchos **(sin mucho tiempo para analizarlo)** donde coloques mas de un id de rol con el id del tipo de entrenamiento que va a tener vinculado, con el fin de que puedas relacionar a mas de uno

Comment: Vale, creo que he encontrado una solución. La tabla de usuarios es compartida para entrenadores y corredores. Crearé dos tablas más, una para entrenadores y otra para corredores y les relacionaré un id de usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución está en crear una tabla de entrenadores y otra de corredores y relacionarles un ID de la tabla usuarios.